# How to change true to yes in rails and a table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have this statement in a  at the moment datetime.present? I'm wanting it to be yes or no rather than true and false.

Also (know this should really be on another question) How can i give each table column its own id so that for example datetime.present? goes in column 7 rather than column 2

Comment: You are right.  Ask the second question in a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in the model (or concern to affect multiple models) you want to enable the yes/no method.

```
def datetime_present?
    self.datetime.present? ? 'yes' : 'no'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want actual strings such as `yes` or `no`, I am assuming you'll be using this in a view file.

You can use a helper for that to return 'yes' or 'no' instead of true or false like the following.

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
# insert the following

def stringified_boolean bool
  bool ? 'yes' : 'no'
end
```

Then use this method in a view file like the following

```
<%= stringified_boolean(datetime.present?) %>
```